# Find first characters in string

Tags: excel

I have a single column of data with multiple data in each cell. I want to print the first letters of each string

```
A
John Smith // print "JS"
Donald Knuth //print "DK"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could break it up into columns to do similar forumlas, but this one should work:

```
concatenate( Left(A2,1),Mid(A2,Find("",A2)+1,1))
```

If you replace A2 with the cell where your name string is it should work. It uses the space location and grabs the letters based on that.

Some sources:

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/save-time-by-using-excels-left-right-and-mid-string-functions/

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/using-excels-find-and-mid-to-extract-a-substring-when-you-dont-know-the-start-point/